# hvplot graphs with for loop

Tags: pandas, hvplot

I am trying to create `hvplot` graphs with a for a loop but it seems not to working.

```py
for i in [2019,2020,2021]:
    CompanyYear= Company[Company['Year']==i]
    filtered.hvplot.bar(x='CompanyID', y='Sales', rot=90)
```

I know that with `matplotlib` you have to use `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to achieve three plots side by side, one for each year, I suggest you tp use the `holoviews` package. This will work:

```py
import holoviews as hv

hv.Layout([Company[Company.Year==i].hvplot.bar(x='CompanyID', y='Sales',rot=90, label=str(i)) for i in [2019, 2020, 2021]])
```

Otherwise, if you want all of them in the same plot, you have to do an `Overlay`:

```py
hv.Layout([Company[Company.Year==i].hvplot.bar(x='CompanyID', y='Sales',rot=90, label=str(i)) for i in [2019, 2020, 2021]])
```

If you run these commands inside Jupyter Lab/Notebook as the last line of a cell the plots will show up.

Comment: You can also add the `.cols(#)` to the end of the `Layout(...)` call to force a set number of columns.